# How to add a separate input field event to a datepicker onSelect event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to enable a disabled select field when a date is selected in a datepicker. I can get the jQuery 'removeAttr('disabled') to trigger outside of the onselect event but not inside.

I've tried onClose and onChange instead of onSelect but they don't seem to be working. I've also tried making a separate function and calling it within the onSelect function but it looks like the scope isn't allowing me to do so.

Here's the html:

```html
<div class="input-field col s3">
    <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate">
    <label>Event Start Date</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s3">
    <select id="startTime" disabled="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose time</option>
        <option value="1">8:00</option>
        <option value="2">8:30</option>
        <option value="3">9:00</option>
        <option value="4">9:30</option>
        <option value="5">10:00</option>
    <select>
</div>
```

Here's the Javascript

```
  $('#startDate').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(date){
      $('#startTime').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
```

I expect the startTime input field to become enabled like what happens with a function outside of the onSelect function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi have you try to use `blur` event on your date picker. for example something like this `$('#startDate').bind('blur',function(){put your code here})` in this way when your date picker loose focus you can enable your select field.

Comment: That does not work sadly.
  $('#startDate').bind('blur', function(){
    $('#startTime').attr('disabled', false);
  })

I think the problem is with Materialize.